# How do I grab the last string from a index by detecting the comma?

Tags: c#

How do I grab the last string from a index by detecting the comma?
Example:
string i = a,b,c,d or i = ab, cd, ef, gh
(the string of i can by dynamic)
So how do I get the last string from the i?? (I need the answer with C# and using the low consume performance ways as possible)

result: a = ad, cd, ef
        b = gh

Comment: Im trying to give a scenario that each string in the string i could be different length, like 3(lengths) as 1 string in the i like, i = 123, 456, 789 or 4(lengths) like i = 1234, 5678, 9012

Comment: I'm still not sure what it is you want. It would help if you edited your question to show different possible input strings, and what the extracted substring should be in each case. And, as has already been mentioned, StackOverflow is intended for helping programmers who have already tried something, not for just for people saying "please write a program for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) along with [String.LastIndexOf Method (Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the index of last comma

```
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',')+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
string[] strArr = inputStr.Split(',');
Array.Reverse(strArr);

Debug.Print(strArr[0]);
```

**Note:** Even if the string does not have a `,`(comma), this piece of code will not crash.

Hope it helps!